# Difficulty summing items from a large string of numbers using foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I have been trying one of the Project Euler challenges but I have gotten stuck with an annoying problem.

```
double sum = 0;
string numbers = "3710728753390210279...."

foreach (int item in numbers) sum += item;

Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

When I run this code it doesn't split each number how I expect it to e.g. the first number 3 will instead be 51 and the second number 7 will be 55. I don't understand where it gets these numbers from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ASCII value of the character 3 is 51

Comment: `foreach` treats its collection as `IEnumerable`, and you are passing a `String`, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`. In C#, `char` has an implicit conversion to `int`, namely the value of the character in the code set (ASCII/Unicode).

Comment: Why do you have `sum` as a `double`?

Comment: If this is regarding Project Euler Problem 13 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=13), your approach does not lead to the correct solution. You have an array (or a string) of 100 numbers, each with 50 digits, and are asked to provide the first 10 digits of the sum of all these 50-digit numbers. In C# this is relatively trivial using System.Math.BigInteger and LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers here haven't explained why you are seeing those unexpected numbers.

I think you are probably expecting the loop `foreach (int item in numbers)` to loop through the individual "numbers" in the string and automatically cast these numbers to integers. That's not what's happening (well, it is, but not how you expect).

The `foreach` loop is converting the `string` to `IEnumerable<char>` and iterating through each `char` character in the string starting `'3', '7', '1', ...`.

In `.Net` characters and strings are encoded in [unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) UTF-16 (as @TomBlodget pointed out in the comments).  This means that each `char` can be converted to it's character code unit.  Your code will actually sum the character code units.

In `C#` the code units for the characters `'0', '1',..,'9'` is in the range 48,...,57.  For this reason you can do something like @Yeldar's answer:

```
foreach (char item in numbers) 
    sum += item - '0';     //  if item == '9' this is equivalent to 57 - 48 = 9
```

So, if the string only contains numbers then subtracting the `'0'` character will implicitly convert the `char` to it's `int` counterpart and you will end up with the actual numerical value it represents (ie `'7' - '0' => 55 - 48 = 7`).

The other answers here provide solutions to overcome the issue.   I thought it would be useful explain why it was happening.

Comment: .NET text datatypes use the UTF-16 character encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set; not ASCII. (Just like JavaScript, Java, VB4/5/6/A/Script, …)

Comment: @TomBlodget that's true. But the designers of C# chose to implicitly convert `char` to `int` using the ASCII value for some reason. My answer has nothing to do with the character set encoding used in C#

Comment: @Haldo - No, it's not right to say "the designers of C# chose to implicitly convert `char` to `int` using the ASCII value". It is simply the case that a `char` has the ASCII value. What they did do, which is different, was overload mathematical operators on `char` to return an `int`.

Comment: Please don't use to the term "ASCII value" when not referring to the ASCII character set or encoding. A more generic term is character code. Or with different specific contexts, codepoint (for a member of a character set) or code unit (for the result of applying a character encoding to a codepoint). In the case of .NET text data types, the values are UTF-16 code units.

Comment: @TomBlodget thank you for your comments. Would the wording be (more) correct if I changed it to "Your code will actually sum the character codes (using ASCII character set)" and "The character codes for the characters `'0', '1',...'9'` (using ASCII character set) is...".  I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Why is the existence of a character set and encoding called ASCII relevant to a system that doesn't use them? (Can you identify a system that does and cite its specification? One answer is [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) But would it be relevant to C#?)

Comment: @TomBlodget I understand what you mean... it's not relevant. actually embarrassed by my response to your first comment now!

Comment: Learning is hard; Un-learning is harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string only contains numerals then this works:

```
string numbers = "3710728753390210279";
int sum = numbers.Sum(x => x - '0');
```

If you're not sure it contains only numerals then this will filter out non-numerals:

```
int sum = numbers.Where(char.IsDigit).Sum(x => x - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there are only digits in a string, then you can actually subtract the value of char `'0'`, which will do the magic for you:

```
int sum = 0;
string numbers = "371";

foreach (char item in numbers) 
    sum += item - '0';

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Please, note that there is `char` in `foreach` so that there is no implicit cast to `int`. And also `int` is used for `sum`, instead of `double`, because you don't actually need a floating-point number here.

Comment: This is a succinct solution, note that it has no fault tolerance, and will produce unexpected results if the string contains anything but numbers

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little more verbose but it will let you see clearly what is happening and will also exclude any non-numeric characters that may pop up in the string:

```
double sum = 0;
string numbers = "3710728753390210279";

foreach (char item in numbers)
{
    int intVal;
    if(int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out intVal))
        sum += intVal;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```